# Differentiate between Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy Tab in UDEV rule?

Tags: udev, android

I love Samsung devices, I have a Samsung Series 9 Laptop, Galaxy Nexus Phone (SCH-i515), and a Galaxy Tab 8.9 (GT-P7310) Tablet. For the most part, they're all great products. Samsung made one major mistake though; the vendor and product IDs (as well as other attributes) of both Android devices are the SAME!

I have a UDEV rule written which runs a script to mount (mtpfs) the Galaxy Nexus when plugged in, after which, it will automatically sync photos and use `notify-send` to create a nice little Gnome notification when the sync is done.

I want something similar to happen when the tablet is plugged in, but with a different mount point, not syncing photos (I don't use the camera on the tab), etc.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to turn at this point. `mtpfs` sees them as the same device as well. Any thoughts on where to turn next?

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the "serial" field... I guess that answers the question :/

Answer (score 1):

As much as i know, with UDEV you can create a role with a lot of details to be matched or not, and i am pretty sure that there is some difference between the devices, so create a new role to exploit these differences and sever the tablet device you have.

You can see the device detail with:

`udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/mouse1)`, where the `/dev/input/mouse1` is just an example.

In order to find what `/dev` node you tablet occupies you should use `udevadm monitor` and then plug-in you tablet.